# Automatically propagating changes

Tags: programming-practices, version-control, code-reuse

When working on multiple similar projects there are often changes that can't be extracted into a library, but should be applied to most of the projects. I mean changes like a modified directory structure, some common configuration, similar ui code, etc.

The most basic strategy is to copy a new project from the last finished one and throw out the business logic. The problem is that the improvements to the newest project won't move back to the older ones.

A slightly better strategy is to set up a boilerplate repository, clone every new project from it. Then the reusable bits can be extracted form the newest project  into the boilerplate and then pulled to the older projects. Of course, merging might be complicated, but I've had this strategy work quite well for me. Pushing the changes is still too much work though.

Is there a strategy to automate propagation of *some* changes across multiple projects?

Answer (score 2):

What you're essentially referring to is a platform.  While I see that it is used to "push off" from a certain project skeleton, with a little work, you can turn this into a platform library.  The advantages are that you can simply update the library to apply the changes to any project you're working on, and any project that is better left untouched can stay with a specific version of the platform.

In order to make this work, you have to take a look at a template class, and turn it into a class that can be simply extended to receive most of its benefits.  Or, in the case of specific usage of a class that you think could be useful in other projects, generalize all of its more common features and again, put it in a class that can be simply extended later.  If you have code generation (I would avoid it if possible, but assuming you can't), try to make it interact directly with your platform classes or at the least, doesn't prevent you later from extending functionality in classes that inherit from them.  Additionally, I strongly advise you to assign versions to your platforms, even if you don't use them at first.  They may come in handy later in order to know what features are permitted in the platform.

Resource files such as libraries can be loaded automatically by the platform, the code for which would be within the platform itself.  Therefore any project using that platform simply has to follow the guidelines for a standard platform hierarchy in order to properly load these resources.  For example, if my platform looks for libraries in a folder called lib, libraries that the platform uses are put in lib, and any additional libraries can be added in later with no extra hassle.

For any given project under a given platform, updating the platform is literally a question of updating its platform library.  For situations where a platform expects certain types of files in a given folder which has since changed from the previous version, the platform itself can be designed to rename older folders.  An example of this could be be that you've decided to handle multiple configuration profiles, one in each folder, but you start off with one configuration file.  Your platform, when run, could copy that configuration into its own folder with the names of default configuration profiles.  The platform, after this initialization phase, will then load the configuration in its own folder (perhaps designating one as a default profile when none is specified).

Unfortunately for situations where the platform cannot fill in the blanks, you will be obliged to correct these changes manually.  A good way to version platforms is to consider major version changes as changes to the platform which require manual intervention to make it work properly.

However also keep in mind that platforms are notoriously known for growing quite complex, due to trying to fulfill every project's requirements in the platform.  This can be avoided simply by asking yourself if a certain modification being made to the platform is one that most of your projects will use and the ones that don't will not be affected.

Also, another piece of advice before starting is, if you haven't already, get the input of your colleagues about what should be the de facto standard project hierarchy before establishing one yourself, otherwise you will likely see your programmer colleagues build their projects in the way that *they* prefer, which defeats the whole purpose of having a platform.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by platform? Is it just a large library?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Yes, the structure remains the same, however you lean on a library to perform common operations like resource loading, which can also rearrange the structure according to what you require.  By updating the platform, you can also keep your project structures in line.

Answer (score 0):

Some environment / IDE allow for project templates.  Depending on your environment this is done differently but I'd be surprised it would not be available.

You can then create a project that contains this template and change it as you would any other projects.  Of course once a project has been started you would have to merge the changes manually but a least any new project would start with the latest and greatest, though sometimes it would also be possible to automate updates as well.

- Project templates in Visual studio
- Maven architypes are pretty good too
- Nuget could do the job as well in the .Net world.  It has the additional advantage to update existing projects through some update powershell scripts.
- Eclipse can provide templates as well, you could go as far as creating a plugin to keep your projects up-to-date.

These are the ones that come off the top of my mind, with a bit of research and more details on your specific situation we could come up with targeted solutions.